# Use return value from modal view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a subclassed UIView that looks like this:

[image: item selector]

ItemSelector:

```
class ItemSelector: UIView {
    weak var delegate: ItemSelectorDelegate?
    // ...
    func addButtonPressed(button: UIButton) {
        // called when "+" button is pressed
        let confirmed = delegate?.addItemOrNot() // delegate function
        if confirmed! { /* update ui */ }
    }
}
```

MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, ItemSelectorDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemSelector: ItemSelector!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        itemSelector.delegate = self
    }

    func addItemOrNot() -> Bool {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("AddOrNot", sender: self)
        return ??? // results from modal view controller
    }
}
```

When the "+" button is pressed, a modal view controller containing "Yes"/"No" buttons will show. If the user selects "Yes", the addItemOrNot() function will return true; else it returns false, and the view will remain unchanged. I've already wired the controllers up with segues.

How can I return a boolean value depending on which button I press in the modal view controller? And how can I use the returned value in the addItemOrNot() function?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the purpose making use of delegates.

In

```
func addItemOrNot() -> Bool {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("AddOrNot", sender: self)
    return ??? // results from modal view controller
}
```

Here,

Set your present view controller as the delegate of modal view controller

```
modalViewController.delegate = self
```

When the modal view controller is getting cancelled or say dismissed in that case, Call the delegate method with the boolean value you wish to pass

```
[self.delegate onCancel:YES/NO];
```

This is written when modal view controller is dismissed.

Then once you receive this value you can pass it to the function you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have a question.

As you said, I have set my root VC as the delegate and I used a variable in the root VC to store the boolean to be returned.

 However, is there a way for the addItemOrNot() function to WAIT FOR the result change from the modal VC and receive the value after it's dismissed?

Comment: if you perform the segue as u have shown and before performing segue you are setting the root VC as delegate then that method in root VC will be called from there you can implement what you want.

Comment: I just couldn't directly return the results of the modal vc from another function. Its results (Boolean) is stored in a variable, so it means I am always using the old value **before** it's updated. Is there a way I can replace the "???" in my code with the **immediate** result from the modal VC?

Comment: If you want to achieve this than simply represent the modal VC using
[self presentViewController: modal VC animated: YES completion: ^{ return the value] this way you need no delegate just make the boolean a public variable in the modal VC and pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two viewcontroller as A and B.

now in B take public variable or instance of A.

When presenting B set that instance of A to self from A viewcontroller.

So Your B Vc get instance or reference of A.

now you can call any public function or method of A from 
B by using that instance of A.

So make changes when dismissing B vc by using A's instance declared in B.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I set up a public variable to store the Bool value to be returned, and I get to change the Bool value in B. But is there a way for the function in A to "WAIT FOR" the change of the Bool value, and then return the new value?

Comment: I just couldn't directly return the results of the modal vc from another function. Its results (Boolean) is stored in a variable, so it means I am always using the old value **before** it's updated. Is there a way I can replace the "???" in my code with the **immediate** result from the modal VC?

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is in the Master View Controller, I have a method 'myUnwindAction' which is called when the detail view controller is closed.  The detail view controller stores the "yes" or "no" in the returnMethod value.
unwindSegue is called when the detail view controller is dismissed. In the storyboard, you will need to option-drag the "Exit" segue button in the detail view controller to the Master View Controller.

```
- (IBAction)myUnwindAction:(UIStoryboardSegue*)unwindSegue {
    DetailViewController *dvc = (DetailViewController *)[unwindSegue sourceViewController];
    int returnMethod = [dvc returnMethod];
    NSLog(@"Return Action: %d",returnMethod);
}
```